# How can i process something parallely for list of string elements in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, parallel-processing

I have a an ArrayList of Strings for example

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add("element1");
list.add("element1");
list.add("element1");
```

for every element in this list i have to do some checks by calling few methods and it is possible that some of the elements may throw exceptions but it should not affect for other elements i.e. the program should not stop. How can I process these elements parallely?

Comment: `list.stream().parallel().forEach(e -> doStuffWith(e));`?

Comment: what if there is an exception for one of the 'e' in doStuffWith(e) ??  will it proceed to other e s?

Comment: No.  But you can either change doStuffWith to catch exceptions, or you can write a wrapper method like doStuffQuietlyWith that calls doStuffWith and catches exceptions.